# Mockito Kotlin rejects to work with extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

In my unit tests, I have a pretty simple case - mocked class with a method call mocking. Something like this:

```
@Mock
private lateinit var feedbackManager: FeedbackManager
...
Mockito.`when`(feedbackManager.sendFeedbackToEmail(any())).thenReturn(Completable.complete())
```

So this works perfectly, and I can mock and verify the method call. No problem.

I decided to improve this a bit and added an extension to my `FeedbackManager` which looks like this:

```
fun FeedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText: String = any()) {
    Mockito.`when`(this.sendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText)).thenReturn(Completable.complete())
}
```

As you can see **everything is the same** inside this extension as it was before adding it.
But for some reason this approach doesn't work:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
package.FeedbackManagerMockingKt.mockSendFeedbackToEmail, parameter feedbackText
```

Can you please advise here?
Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `any()` wasn't working correctly in any case: as a parameter, inside a function, as an argument.
So the solution for me was to inline this function (adding an `inline` modifier).

```
inline fun FeedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText: String = any()) {
    Mockito.`when`(this.sendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText))
        .thenReturn(Completable.complete())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ArgumentMatchers.any()` returns `null`, which does not play well with Kotlin non-nullable types. If it works in your first snippet, then the `sendFeedbackToEmail` argument must be nullable I guess (or it's a Java class). But the `feedbackText` in the `mockSendFeedbackToEmail` is not nullable, so Kotlin compiler inserts null-checks there. Thus the NullPointerException.

Try changing the method signature to:

```kotlin
fun FeedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText: String? = any()) {
  ...
}
```

If the `sendFeedbackToEmail` argument is not nullable and you are using `com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin`, you can try the following:

```
fun FeedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText: String? = null) {
    Mockito.`when`(this.sendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText ?: any())).thenReturn("OK")
}
```

or just overload the function instead of using default value (to avoid a bit misleading calls like: `feedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail(null)`):

```
fun FeedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail() {
    Mockito.`when`(this.sendFeedbackToEmail(any())).thenReturn("OK")
}

fun FeedbackManager.mockSendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText: String) {
    Mockito.`when`(this.sendFeedbackToEmail(feedbackText)).thenReturn("OK")
}
```

Comment: I can't, cause the actual method `feedbackManager.sendFeedbackToEmail(any())` doesn't work with nullable types.And I'm using `com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin` - it works fine with kotlin+nullable, etc.